Why is katallage in Isaiah 9:5 (LXX) left out of most English translations?
I'm digging into the word katallage in the New Testament (Strong's G2644) and decided to see if it appears in the Septuagint. I found it in Isaiah 9:5 (sometimes appears as 9:4). But no translation has the English word "reconciliation/restitution" in this verse. Well, Brenton's translation does, but that's it:

For they shall compensate for every garment that has been acquired by deceit, and all raiment with restitution; and they shall be willing, even if they were burnt with fire.


Why is this word—restitution/reconciliation—left out of so many translations (including the Vulgate), when it is clearly in the Septuagint? (A photo image of the Codex Sinaticus depicts this Greek word clearly in Isaiah 9:5).

How did it make it into the Septuagint when there appears to be no corresponding Hebrew word?



The Hebrew Masoretic text of Isa 9:5 as we now have it reads as follows (my overly literal translation):

For every warrior's boot from noisy [battle] plus garments rolled in
blood, will be used as burning fuel of fire.

The LXX of the same verse reads (Brenton):

For they shall compensate for every garment that has been acquired by
deceit, and all raiment with restitution; and they shall be willing,
even if they were burnt with fire.

The Lamsa translation of the Aramaic text reads:

For every voice which is heard brings terror and garments rolled in
blood; but this shall be for burning and fuel for fire.

The Latin Vulgate as translated by the DRB is:

For every violent taking of spoils, with tumult, and garment mingled
with blood, shall be burnt, and be fuel for the fire.

It is immediately obvious that all these texts are similar with the conspicuous exception of the LXX which presumably used a quite different exemplar from the Masoretic Text.  This is simply another of the many thousands of places where the LXX shows significant differences from the MT.

Got it. Thanks.

Well-spoken.  a thorough treatment.
